# Full access to one Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iam-authenticator

I don't use AWS a lot, but I wrote one small lambda function and I want to give someone full access.  Everytime I try to add the user the IAM permissions it never seems to give enough access or show even the correct function. I feel like this should be a simple task.
One function, with logs and SNS. Can someone help with the JSON permission needed to access this specific resource?

Comment: How does your permission look like right now? Is it cross-account and/or cross-region? Is the user an IAM user or some role?

Comment: IAM user.  I managed to get most working. But it won't let me upload a zip as code for the lambda- when I test the new user login.

Answer (score 0):

A Lambda function is triggered by a so-called event source. An event source is an AWS service so you need to give the lambda function enough access to that service.

Two ways I recommend you to do it:

1. Go to the AWS Lambda page and create one:
   Use the blueprint `microservice-http-endpoint` lambda function as sample and click configure.
   It will create a new permission for you as you will see in that config page
2. This one is just a test and should not be used in production:
   Create a new Role and name it test, and attatch it this policies:

[image]

and either attach that role to your existing lambda or create a new one with it.

That should help :)